# Receive email in real-time from many email account with Mailkit

Tags: mailkit

I am using Mailkit Idle Client to receive email in real-time from one email account. It's OK.
Is it possible to do it with many accounts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible - you would just need to have 1 ImapClient (and IdleClient) per account.

Comment: Thanks jstedfast, if I have 100 accounts (saved in MSSQL), I will need to have 100 ImapClient? How to configure it

Comment: Correct. I have no idea what you are asking with the second part of your question. You don't "configure" anything in MailKit, so that makes no sense to me.